# New spreadsheet & copyFormatTo

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a new spreadsheet document, and i set the formatting to range of cells.

First problem:
When I try send response from my form, form is adding new row without formatting (my formatting range include this new row).

Second Problem:
When i try use function copyFormatTo() in Google Apps Script, GAS gives me error about "Spreadsheet error".

Sample code from documentation - the same error:
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var source = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = source.getRange("B2:D4");

// This copies the data in B2:D4 in the source sheet to
 // D4:F6 in the sheet with gridId 0
 range.copyFormatToRange(0, 4, 6, 4, 6);

Could you help me solve problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get the destination sheet first and then call `copyFormatToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd)` version. It works for me.